How to replay game dynamically and in slow motion?
I have a problem in ultimate replay package script, I have this code:
using UnityEngine;
using UltimateReplay;
    
namespace ultimateReplay
{
    public class ReplayManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private ReplayHandle replayHandle;
    
        void Start()
        {
            replayHandle = ReplayManager.BeginRecording();
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {
                replayHandle = ReplayManager.BeginRecording();
                Debug.Log("Recording started");
            }
    
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                ReplayManager.StopRecording();
                Debug.Log("Recording stopped");
            }
    
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
            {
                ReplayManager.BeginPlayback(replayHandle);
                Debug.Log("Playback started");
            }
    
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
            {
                ReplayManager.StopPlayback();
                Debug.Log("Playback stopped");
            }
        }
    }
}

but replayManager.StopRecording() and
replayManager.BeginPlayback(replayHandle) and
replayManager.StopPlayback() throw errors.
I want to replay my game's result, I do one race game. It has a result scenario, after that scenario, I want to replay the winning result.
How do I do this? I want replay in slow motion.
I want to import ultimate Replay package in unity Asset Store.

you said it had errors, but didnt include what - you also need to remember you are asking about code to a single item on the asset store, which reduces the number of people who have used it.. However, you need to explain more what exactly isnt working and by the looks of it this asset has a good number of examples to get you going
